# SharePoint 2013 Community Site feasibility

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, community-site, community

Is it feasible to create SharePoint 2013 Community Site as a public facing site. Is there any SharePoint public facing site with Community Site features enabled.